# Javascript / jQuery: Any event for history.go(-1)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, events, post

In my server side validation of a form, I am using `history.go(-1);` to redirect back in case of validation error. This way form data remains there and user can fix data and resubmit the form.

It works well until I use captcha. If user submits wrong captcha, the server validation redirects him back using `history.go(-1);`. This way, the page is not actually reloading and captcha image dosen't refresh. So the user keeps submitting wrong captcha.

So is there any way I can trigger an event or function every time page is redirected back via `history.go(-1);`. This way I can call a function which would reload captcha image.

I have to do it this way, because my form processing is being done on a separate server.

Thanks.

Comment: `history.go(-1)` is a lazy solution, besides how do you display errors if you're going back?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution here is to make the captcha image not cacheable. You need to instruct your captcha script to send a response header with the image, either with a "expires" date in the past or a no cache one. That way, the browser will reload the captcha on every history.go(-1).

Answer (score 1):

The [`window.onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onpopstate) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think youu need an history adapter:

```
History.Adapter.bind (window, 'statechange', function () {});
```

this will trigger the funcion at each history state change.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = location.href;
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    if(url != location.href) {
        /*Your Function here
         * I'm using this to load the contentBox when user goes back or forward in  
         * browserhistory -- perfect for sites with ajax
         * works on all browser but u need Jquery. (Safari can't use window.location.href)
         * for functions to add dynamic params or removing them just ask ;)
         * define the url var to prevent function to fire on reload
         */
    }
};
```